# How do you update Visual Studio 2017 to latest release?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm used to seeing an update option in Help About. How do you update the Visual Studio 2017 IDE to the latest version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While in the Visual Studio 2017 IDE, you'll see a yellow flag in the title bar that indicates that at least one notification is waiting:

[image]

You can single-click that flag icon to view the notifications. If you see an update, you can click the link. That takes you to the Extensions and Updates window.

But to get to updates when you might have dismissed notifications or when you don't see the yellow-flag icon, you can get to that window directly. To do that, go to Tools | Extensions and Updates. On the left pane select Updates. You'll see a list of available updates. To install one, click the Update button. In the image below, Visual Studio Update 15.1 (26403.7) is available and its Update button appears on the right edge of the selected item.

[image]